# jqGrid - how to return result of row edit?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Im attempting to edit a row using the inline editor as follows:

```
ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {
        jQuery(this).jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid,
           {width:500,Height:400,recreateForm:true,closeAfterEdit:true,
            closeOnEscape:true,reloadAfterSubmit:true,
              editData: {
                 SubjId: $( "#list0" ).jqGrid ( 'getCell', rowid, 'SubjId' ),
                 a: 1,
                 SeqId: $( "#list0" ).jqGrid ( 'getCell', rowid, 'SequenceId' )
              },
              afterSubmit: function( response, postData )
              {
                  alert( response.responseText );
              }
        });
```

Editor is defined in the jqGrid definition as 'editurl: <edit.php>'

Two questions:

1. The php code is getting the edit request from the grid dialog but I'm not clear on how to return the result.
2. Tried returning using a simple `echo 0` (as is the case for many Ajax requests) but am getting an error in the jqgrid code:

file **jquery.jqGrid.src.js** line 7936: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

jqGrid is coming via `//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqgrid/4.6.0/`

Suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **return array** from `afterSubmit` callback. Add for example `return [true];` at the end of `afterSubmit` to fix the problem